# Save output of a void function to .txt file

Tags: c++, file

I have a `void draw()` function in a class that outputs the data members of the class on the screen.
Is there a way to save all of the data to a `.txt` file using this same `draw()` function?

I thought about adding an aid function which receives an returns `ostream&`, and calls `draw()`:

```
ostream& Widget::aid(ostream& tt) const
{
    draw();
    return tt;
}
```

Problem is, that an address is saved to the file instead of data when I try to do it this way.

Comment: Is it a solution to call the program ./program > file.txt ? That will save all the program output to file.txt in most Linux distros. Also your proposed solution will change nothing, since draw() is most probably using std::cout or printf().

Comment: If your `draw()` function is using `std::cout` then you can use `cout.rdbuf(newbuffer)` by associating it to other destination.

Comment: I would modify the draw() signature to receive the following `draw(ostream &tt = std::cout)` so if no ostream is given it will print out on the console

Comment: I guess i dont understand if your trying to save the image that you are trying to draw or if you want to save the values of the members being drawn. If its the second one than you could just make another function to do that and add another call as it doesnt make sense to do the storing of the info in the draw function as they are unrelated. EDIT: the title for this doesnt make any sense. The drfinition of a void function is it produces no output. I suspect you might need to make it return something.

Comment: @Neil Locketz, what should it return in order for it to save to a file? &fstream

Comment: Just pipe the output of your program to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the draw() function uses stdout ( e.g. cout ), you can simply execute

```
freopen("my.txt","w",stdout);
```

before calling draw.

Comment: But I still call `draw` using `aid`?

Comment: It works! I'm actually surprised.
should I remove the `fstream fs("data.txt", std::ios::out);` line that is located at the start of the block? and leave only the `freopen` one?

Comment: The only problem is, that after the writing to the file is done, the program is waiting for user input, even I i enter a character it still waits for one, why?

Comment: I only added:
    freopen("my.txt","w",stdout);
    draw();
    fclose (stdout);
No such issues before that.

Comment: Didn't help.
what about previous `std::fstream fs("data.txt", std::ios::out);` line? should i remove it if I'm using fopen